# How to speed up UICollectionView cell rendering in tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, tvml

I have developed a tvOS application that renders a `CollectionView` inside of a `CollectionView`. Each section of the first `CollectionView` has only 1 element, let's call it `RowCell`, and this element contains the second `CollectionView`, that has many cells of that given category.

The problem I have is:
when I use `.reloadData()` in the `prepareForReuse` method in the `RowCell` (the row that contains the cells separated by categories) it loads extremely slow when I scroll up and down. And if I don't use `.reloadData()` for the `RowCell`, the data always get rendered wrong.

Any thoughts about how to use `.reloadData()` and don't decrease scrolling/rendering speed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you’re probably blocking the main thread, perhaps downloading data, rendering/formatting images, etc. You should do that work on a background thread. You can try using the time profiler to see what’s using up so much time.

Answer (score 1):

There were two simple problems with it. First, every cell was loading heavy images from the internet, so I request for lower quality alternatives in the API and the second one is that these images were not being saved in Cache, so I had to do it every in every user scroll. By implementing both of these solutions, all problems went away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you have many categories, you're doing a lot of `reloadData()`. That gets worse if the inner collection view's cells requires hard work to be rendered, despite of cell reusing. To mitigate that, you may want to take a look in [Prefetching Collection View Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching/prefetching_collection_view_data), where you can prefetch required data and perform hard work asynchronously for cells before they actually display.

Also, if that's possible, I suggest you to take a look in [IGListKit](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit), a third-party library developed by Instagram that claims to be a tool for building `flexible` and `fast` lists. I myself used IGListKit and it is, indeed, a really good option for creating the kind of collection view you want. The problem is that its learning curve can be steep.

Hope this helps!